# splitting a dataframe column into two, with one column contains numbers the other text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column that contains numbers and text. I want to split the column into two columns, one column with just the numbers and the other with just text. Is this possible?

Through searching on here I found an example below, however this leaves my column unchanged.

```
chk = df['messy_column'].str.split('(\d+)([A-Za-z]+)', expand=True)
```

Example of my data,

```
messy_column
.965 pb ./ sm
16.3 /pb
0.33 aq.ht
```

**expected output**

```
 num_column      text_column
   0.965           pb ./ sm
   16.3            /pb
   0.33            aq.ht
```

Comment: provide expected output for sample data

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar apologies should have done that in my original post... now upadted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `str.split`:

```
df['messy_column'].str.split('(?<=\d)(\s+).*?', expand=True).drop(1, axis=1)

    0         2
0   965  pb ./ sm
1  16.3       /pb
2  0.33     aq.ht
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it works perfectly for what I showed. I just found one row where the value is 120.3/pbh. which it doesn't seem to work for?